# Salesforce Marketing Cloud RetrieveSalesforceOgject

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am planning to use Marketing Cloud Journey Builder to send emails based on case status changes in sales cloud. We are connected with MCconnect.  Apparently I need to use RetrieveSalesforceObject formula in the email to surface different fields on the case/order/orderItem objects. We are using the contactid as our subscriber id. Can someone point me toward resources or share additional information on examples, syntax, gotchas and how to use this formula? I've tried a few times and keep getting stuck.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here’s the RetrieveSalesforceObject function: https://ampscript.guide/retrievesalesforceobjects/, but I wouldn’t use it in an email as it could affect performance. I suggest synching the case data and using lookups to Synchronized Data Extensions instead

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I am still struggling with this. I do have Synchronized Data Extensions, but i need data from 3 different objects/extensions.  I want to send an email to each Order in a specific status. That email will have the order detail and will need to pull all of the product line items associated with that order.  The subscriber key is our contact. A contact may have multiple orders at one time.

I have created a SQL query for the contact and order, and another one to join contact, order, and order product.

I thought i could use a lookup into the contact and order data extension and then a lookuprows into the contact/order/orderproduct to get the rest of the info, but its not working.

Do i need all of the fields in the same data extension? How can i get the right starting order? I am clearly very new to this. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!